# Is it possible to remove a page during document creation, like a "transaction" in databases

Tags: itext

I have some code that generates documents using the Document, PdfWriter and PdfResource.  As it loops through the generation of the PDF, it creates new pages.  Sometimes, there may be a condition where the generation of the new page fails, and the page should not be added.  Is there a way to handle pages "transactionally". i.e. create a page and enter content, if it fails, "rollback" the changes and do not add the page to the document?

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
pdfResource.document.newPage();

PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
contentByte.saveState();

try {
    // do some work to fill the page
} catch (Exception e) {
    // How do I rollback and remove the page???
} finally {
    contentByte.restoreState();
}
```

I am currently using version 5.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to do what you are trying to do.

The recommended path would be to do the "try/catch" stuff *before* you call `newPage()`. Set up some state variables variables, perform your sanity tests, etc. If you're working with images make sure that you can actually read them. I would actually go so far as to instantiate/load the image bytes beforehand.

Another option would be to mark those pages as "to delete at the end" and then call `pdfReader.selectaPages()` on everything except those.

Comment: Looks like selectpages may work. Thanks for the reply, Chris!  -Todd